# Mapping two graphs database in ArangoDB

Tags: graph, arangodb

Kindly ask to know if I can link (map) two graphs together in ArangoDB?
I have two distinct graphs that I need to merge them into one graph, can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by you already have two graphs? Two named graphs in ArangoDB's sense?

Comment: I mean I have two graphs database 
For example:
I have a graph that contains edges and documents of the first university and its students, and another graph that contains edges and document of another university.
I want to know if I can combine these two graphs together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edges in ArangoDB can point to any document in any collection. There is no real concept of distinct graphs therefore.

You could import `userA`, `userB` and `userC` from dataset 1 into a `students` collection, and `userD` and `userE` from dataset 2 as well. Same goes for universities. Edges in an edge collection `studiesAt` can refer to arbitrary student and university documents in the `_from` and `_to` attributes.